# is it possible atmega 2560 replication

Tags: arduino

i am using  atmega 2560. i want to burn another 2560 ic without using a computer. ie, using atmega2560 as programmer. please help me.

Comment: You can't turn an atmega2560 into a programmer without using a computer.

Comment: @DaveTweed - you can most certainly do so without using an *additional* computer - there is for example a well-known Arduino sketch that autonomously loads a bootloader into a target, to get around the many communication difficulties beginners often have with slave-programmer setups.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: So how do you get that sketch into the Arduino? You need a computer at *some* point in the process! The way the question is worded, it sounds like he wants one chip to automatically clone itself into a second, completely blank chip. I'd be happy to migrate this to Arduino.SE, but only if the OP puts some effort into clarifying what it is he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: No, that is not what it says at all.  It says "burn another 2560 without using a computer"  Note the word "another"

Answer (score 2):

Several people use one Atmel ATmega processor to "burn in" a program into the flash memory of another Atmel ATmega processor, in places where they don't have a full-sized laptop computer.
Since it happens, therefore it must be possible.

The simplest approach seems to be:

1. use a full-sized computer ahead of time to write and compile the destination programs and store them on an SD card ahead of time
2. burn the "I'm a flash programmer" program into one microprocessor
3. Turn the full-sized computer off and put it away. Use the one ATmega2560 microprocessor to copy those programs from the SD card and force them into the program memory of any number of destination ATmega2560 processors, one at a time.
4. (Optional) If the "I'm a flash programmer" program is one of the programs on the SD card, that program can be burned into a destination processor in the same way.

### details

- "[µProg – tiny, fast, portable AVR programmer with SD](http://mdiy.pl/uprog-maly-szybki-przenosny-programator-avr-z-sd/?lang=en) ... Helps wherever you need to update the device firmware, where target device is in a hard-to-reach location and you can’t (or don’t want to) bring your laptop with a bunch of wires with you."
- "[Phoenard ... can be re-programmed](http://phoenard.com/what-is-phoenard/) using programs stored on a Micro-SD card, allowing you to switch between functions anywhere you like... without requiring a bulky computer."
- [Arduino Mega2560 as ISP to program another Arduino Mega2560](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=126160.0)
- [Using an Arduino as an AVR ISP (In-System Programmer)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP)
- [How to Program a AVR (arduino) With Another Arduino](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-program-a-AVR-arduino-with-another-arduin/) by kabturek
- [Program an Arduino with another Arduino](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/57947/l/program-an-arduino-with-another-arduino?displayFullThread=true)